# Cannot create temporary table in view definition PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, temp-tables, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE  VIEW  viewRebalancingLog AS


CREATE TEMP TABLE newSessionID
(
  ilog_id INT,vch_service_name VARCHAR(200), vch_service_id  VARCHAR(200),iuser_id INT,vch_session_id  VARCHAR(200),
  isequence_id INT,vch_message_type  VARCHAR(200),vch_message_sub_type  VARCHAR(200),vch_message  VARCHAR,
  dt_service_log_time TIMESTAMP,dt_inserted_date TIMESTAMP
)


 INSERT INTO newSessionID
      ("ilog_id", "vch_service_name", "vch_service_id"  , "iuser_id" , "vch_session_id"  , "isequence_id" ,
  "vch_message_type"  ,"vch_message_sub_type","vch_message","dt_service_log_time","dt_inserted_date"
)
SELECT
     "LOGS"."ilog_id", "LOGS"."vch_service_name","LOGS"."vch_service_id","LOGS"."iuser_id" ,"LOGS"."vch_session_id"  ,
  "LOGS"."isequence_id" ,"LOGS"."vch_message_type"  ,"LOGS"."vch_message_sub_type" ,"LOGS"."vch_message",
  "LOGS"."dt_service_log_time","LOGS"."dt_inserted_date"
  FROM services_logs_stg AS "LOGS"
   WHERE ("LOGS".dt_service_log_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') :: DATE =
         (((NOW() -
           INTERVAL '2 day')  :: TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') :: DATE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't create temp table inside VIEW. Check [CREATE VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html):

> CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] [ TEMP | TEMPORARY ] [ RECURSIVE ] VIEW name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
>           [ WITH ( view_option_name [= view_option_value] [, ... ] ) ]
>           AS query

Why not use simple `CREATE VIEW ... AS SELECT`:

```
CREATE  VIEW  viewRebalancingLog AS
SELECT
     "LOGS"."ilog_id", "LOGS"."vch_service_name","LOGS"."vch_service_id","LOGS"."iuser_id" ,"LOGS"."vch_session_id"  ,
  "LOGS"."isequence_id" ,"LOGS"."vch_message_type"  ,"LOGS"."vch_message_sub_type" ,"LOGS"."vch_message",
  "LOGS"."dt_service_log_time","LOGS"."dt_inserted_date"
  FROM services_logs_stg AS "LOGS"
   WHERE ("LOGS".dt_service_log_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') :: DATE =
         (((NOW() -
           INTERVAL '2 day')  :: TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') :: DATE;
```

If you need some sort of intermediate steps consider using [`common table expressions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html).

**EDIT:**

> No,this is not end of the Query that i have posted, i have more temp table and JOIN each other. my goal is: 1.create temp table1, 2.insert data in temp table1 than 3.create temp table 2 4.insert data in temp table 2 5.create temp table 3 6.insert data from temp1 join temp2 7. select * from temp3

You could simply use `CTE` as I proposed before:

```
WITH temp1 AS (
    SELECT  ...
    FROM ...
), temp2 AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
)
SELECT *
FROM temp1
JOIN temp2
  ON ...
```

Comment: no, i have to use temp table under that. any other solution.please help.

Comment: @DhurjatiBorah: why do you think you "have" to use a temp table? The view in this answer will return exactly the same data as your (incorrect) view

Comment: No,this is not end of the Query that i have posted,
i have more temp table and JOIN each other.
my goal is:
1.create temp table1,
2.insert data in temp table1
than 
3.create temp table 2
4.insert data in temp table 2

5.create temp table 3
6.insert data from 
temp1 join temp2

7. select * from temp3

Comment: @DhurjatiBorah Still I don't see the point of temporary tables. CTE will be sufficient.

Comment: @DhurjatiBorah: that doesn't make sense if the result of the view depends on a bunch of inserts then a view is the wrong tool for this. I highly doubt all those temp tables are really necessary (are you porting from SQL Server?). Typically you would simply join/union those queries in the view. Why do you think you _need_ all those temp tables? Why can't you simply create one single query? If you really think you need this, a set returning function is the way to go

Comment: correct. now i use select queries and joinand unions each others.
Thanks for the help.